# Python: store current page URL to variable in Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium, but this specific page is preventing me from simply using `"driver.current_url"`, as it just outputs a generic URL to mask the real one. If you want to try it for yourself: https://render-state.to/crypt-of-the-damned/. Follow the Google Drive link.

As an alternative, I am trying to use `keyboard inputs` to copy the `web address` of the current page in Chrome:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import keyboard
import win32clipboard

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

START_PAGE = "https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.send"
driver.get(START_PAGE)

keyboard.send('alt+d') # select text in address bar
keyboard.send('ctrl+c') # should copy to clipboard, but does not.

win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

print (data)
```

Using these resources:
https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases
https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.send

[][][][][][][][][][][][][][] EDIT [][][][][][][][][][][][][][]

The intended link to be gathered is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cHPNOfcFh4BAwOBHUuxp3GmV-5a_BaTs/view

There are zero to three intermediary links before the intended one, so anywere between none to all appear. The first two appear in random order:

1. https://render-state.to/exit.php?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Ffile%2Fd%2F1cHPNOfcFh4BAwOBHUuxp3GmV-5a_BaTs%2Fview%3Fusp%3Dsharing... (This is the site's 5 seconds redirect, it can sometimes be seen by inspecting the Google Drive button, but I have not found a way to access this href, except by parsing all hrefs on the page and looking for patterns with regex, which I might try if all else fails. If there is an easier way, it could then be parsed to yield the final intended Google Drive link. However, sometimes it just presents a "http://ay.gy/etc" link that loads the regecish adfly webpage anyway, see below.
2. http://regecish.net/etc... (This is the adfly website, you need to click the skip ad button here once it becomes available).
3. https://iq-option.com/etc... (This sometimes appears after you click the adf.ly skip add button, and ends up being returned instead of the intended link).

Here are codes tested in isolation for each redirect case. I am yet to concatenate them with conditionals for each scenario.

*** Redirect 1:**

```
adfly = driver.find_element_by_link_text('GOOGLE DRIVE').get_attribute('href') # gives a "http://ay.gy/etc" link or a "https://render-state.to/exit.php?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fq.gs%2FExBpX" link that can be parsed to "http://q.gs/etc". Both load the regecish adfly page, hence skipping redirect 1.
```

*** Redirect 2**, wait and click the skip add button on the adfly website:

```
driver.get(adfly)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="skip_bu2tton"]/img'))) 
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "mwButton")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="skip_bu2tton"]/img').click()
```

*** Redirect 3**, when it does appear, loads a random advertising tab, such as iq-option, then immediately creates the final intended tab and activates it.

By trying "driver.current_url" while being ALREADY FOCUSED ON THE GOOGLE DRIVE PAGE, you just end up with one of the three redirects, or the original start page, regardless of implicit or explicit waits.

Comment: Basically when you click on Google driver link it opens new tab, Do you want that new tab URL ?

Comment: why not get link directly from button.

Comment: @furas : That makes sense. I tried to check the href, it seems to be different on button and when opened in new tab, it's quite strange

Comment: @cruisepandey meanwhile I also tried to use Selenium to get link from button and it seems it is some shortcut link which is used by `redirect` to get real url from database. OR maybe it recognizes Selenium and sends different urls

Comment: @furas : That could be the possibility here.

Comment: @cruisepandey When I use this strange link (without `https://render-state.to/exit.php?redirect=`) in web browser then it sends me to page which finally redirect me to Google Drive - so it has to be some shortcut link.

Comment: @furas. Using "driver.find_element_by_link_text('GOOGLE DRIVE').get_attribute('href')" returns redirect URLs, not the Google Drive intended one. Inspecting the Google Drive button, you sometimes see a redirect that can be parsed into the intended one by substituting %X characters for proper ones, but more often you just get more redirects, such as "http://ay.gy/etc", which land on the regecish adfly page.

Comment: meanwhile I tested code and I saw that it uses redirections - but you didn't have it in question when I was writing my first comment. if you knew it before then you should write it in question - so we wouldn't have to waste time for this.

Answer (score 1):

Basically when you click on Google driver link it opens new tab, If you want that new tab URL then :

**Explanation :** The moment you click on Google drive link, it opens up a new tab. We need to tell this to driver that it has to focus on the new tab. Now question is how we are going to communicate this to driver  :

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

using this command.

**Code :**

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://render-state.to/crypt-of-the-damned/")
print(driver.current_url)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "GOOGLE DRIVE")))).click().perform()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
print(driver.current_url)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**Output :**

```
https://render-state.to/crypt-of-the-damned/
http://regecish.net/rweasy/-1VZSY/8138182/_eaHR0cHM6Ly9yZW5kZXItc3RhdGUudG8vZXhpdC5waHA/cmVkaXJlY3Q9aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZkcml2ZS5nb29nbGUuY29tJTJGZmlsZSUyRmQlMkYxY0hQTk9mY0ZoNEJBd09CSFV1eHAzR21WLTVhX0JhVHMlMkZ2aWV3JTNGdXNwJTNEc2hhcmluZw==?rndad=3058446250-1623997494

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: The end url is `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cHPNOfcFh4BAwOBHUuxp3GmV-5a_BaTs/view`. I guess @SevenAltZero wants to fetch this url. If I am not wrong, then adding a wait time of 5 secs will do the job

Comment: @LibinThomas : I still do not see where is that URL. When I clicked on `Google driver` - that opened up a new tab and from there I am retrieving the current url

Comment: Sharing the redirect URL: https://render-state.to/exit.php?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Ffile%2Fd%2F1cHPNOfcFh4BAwOBHUuxp3GmV-5a_BaTs%2Fview%3Fusp%3Dsharing

Comment: That is not the same page when you click on google drive link on that page. OP is very specific to get current URL

Comment: I am redirected to the google drive page on hitting the button `GOOGLE DRIVE`, which I suppose should be the ideal end point. So if we want to fetch redirect url then switching focus to other tab and `driver.current_url` should work. And if we want the endpoint, adding a wait of 5 secs and then `driver.current_url` should work. Let me know if this what is expected from the script.

Comment: Certainly I am not the OP.

Comment: @LibinThomas. I should have been clearer. Intended URL is: https://drive.google.com/file/etc. On my end, the Google Drive page is already focused after all the redirects. Using driver.current_url already on the GD page returns one of the three redirects instead of the GD link, regardless of all implicit and explicit waits that I have tried.

Comment: @SevenAltZero Let me try running the script. I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Will answer my own badly worded question, because this might be of use for those handling redirects.

Found the solution by repetitively fetching the url of all opened tabs and then using regex to find a filehost link among them and parse it to yield the desired final URL. Notice that, in order to avoid Cloudflare, I am also intercepting an existing chrome page launched via command prompt instead of using driver.get().

Test page: https://render-state.to/crypt-of-the-damned/

```
import re
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
# wait precursors
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

print ('RUNNING')

# Intercept running chrome page after launching it via command prompt with:
# chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="C:\selenium\ChromeProfile"
# This avoids Cloudflare.
# Start page = https://render-state.to/crypt-of-the-damned/

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")
chrome_driver = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, options=chrome_options)
print (driver.title)

# Grab adfly link from one the available hosts, in order of preference.
filehosts = ["MEDIAFIRE", "GOOGLE DRIVE", "UPLOADED", "RACATY", "WORKUPLOAD", "ZIPPYSHARE", "YANDEX", "UPLOADHAVEN", "FILES", "PASTEBIN", "GOFILE", "MEGA"]
ADFLY_Links = []            
move = True
xx = 0
while move == True:
    try:
        adfly = driver.find_element_by_link_text(filehosts[xx]).get_attribute('href')
        if adfly.find("render-state") > 0:
            adfly = adfly.replace('https://render-state.to/exit.php?redirect=http%3A%2F%2F','').replace('%2F','/')
        ADFLY_Links.append(adfly)
        print ('{} adfly links listed. {}.'.format(len(ADFLY_Links), filehosts[xx]))
        move = False
    except:
        move = True
        xx += 1

# Open adfly link.
driver.get(adfly)

# Wait adfly locker if it appears.
adfly_wait_lock = driver.current_url
if adfly_wait_lock.find("locked") > 0:
    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
    print ('Waiting adfly lock...')
    time.sleep(20)
    driver.get(adfly)

# Wait for skip add button on regecish, click once available.
print ('Waiting Skip Ad button...')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="skip_bu2tton"]/img'))) 
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "mwButton")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="skip_bu2tton"]/img').click()

# Keep fetching links of all tabs and search them with regex until a filehost link appears.
wait_red = True
time_slept = 1
open_tabs = []
while wait_red:
    for handle in driver.window_handles: # Fetch URL of all tabs. Tried to fetch only relevant one, but had all sorts of annoyance.
        driver.switch_to.window(handle)
        open_tabs.append(driver.current_url)
        open_tabs_str = ''.join(open_tabs)
    to_find = re.compile("mediafire|drive|uploaded|racaty|workupload|zippyshare|yandex|uploadhaven|files|pastebin|gofile|mega")
    search_str = open_tabs_str
    match_obj = to_find.search(search_str)
    if match_obj == None:
        open_tabs = []
        open_tabs_str = ""
        time.sleep(1)
        print ('Waiting redirects... {} s'.format(time_slept))
        time_slept += 1
    else:
        wait_red = False

# Grab download link from fetched URLs.
print ('\n')
try:
    download_link = open_tabs[1] # for when Redirect 3 happens and you have 2 tabs open.
except:
    download_link = open_tabs[0] # For when it doesn't, and you only have 1.
if download_link.find("redirect") > 0: # Grab link from site's redirect if it becomes avaiblabe, avoiding 5 s wait.
    download_link = download_link.replace('https://render-state.to/exit.php?redirect=https%3A%2F%2F', '').replace('%2F', '/')
print (download_link)
```

Final code is actually more sofisticated than this, as it uses code below to skip adfly 5 s wait, handles erros, etc:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("meta")
for elem in elems:
    content = elem.get_attribute("content")
    if content.find('redirecting') > 0:
        skip_adfly = content
        print ('Skipped Adfly')
        driver.get(skip_adfly)
        break
```